# Return only even numbers from the given list

Tags: python, args, keyword-argument

Define a function that takes in an arbitrary number of arguments and returns a list containing only those arguments which are even:

```
def myfunc(*args):
    mylist = []

    for i in range(0,len(args)):
        if args[i] %2 == 0:
            mylist.append(args[i])
    return mylist
```

This code seems very long, is there any way to make it more efficient 
 using *args or *kwargs??

Answer (score 4):

Use an iterator inside of a list comprehension

```
return [i for i in args if i % 2 == 0]
```

Comment: This is not only shorter, it's also going to run faster!

Answer (score 0):

Do this instead:

```
args[0::2]
```

You will get all alternate index as shown:

[image]

Comment: Hey Jackson i think u misunderstood the question,
We have to return the even values
Not the even index places

Comment: def myfunc(*args):
    return [ args[i] for i in range(0,len(args)) if args[i]%2 == 0]

I had to write is this way.
Otherwise it was saying that tuple index is out of range.
What is the reason behind that??

Comment: Your code definition was: mylist.append(args[i]) which is the value and not the index. Do you mean mylist.append(i) instead?

Comment: [**Please do not upload images of text (code/input/output/errors, or otherwise) on Stack Overflow**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). Please [edit] your answer, pasting all text into the answer with [correct formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).